# AWS Lambda SES SMTPLib Email Timing Out Using Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, smtplib

My lambda environment is set up in `us-east-2` however I know SES only is present in `us-east-1`.  This is the code:

```
    sent_from = "email1@gmail.com"
    send_to = "email2@gmail.com"
    aws_user_name = "<USER NAME KEY>"
    #stub - replace this
    aws_password = "<USER PASSWORD KEY>"
    logger.info("send_emails: start")

    for email in email_list:

        try:

            logger.info("send_emails: step 1: smtp")
            server = smtplib.SMTP()
            logger.info("send_emails: step 2: smtp")
            server.connect('email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 587)
            #server.ehlo()
            logger.info("send_emails: step 3: smtp")            
            server.starttls()
            logger.info("send_emails: step 4: smtp")
            #logger.info("User: " + aws_user_user + " Password:" + aws_password)
            server.login(aws_user_name, aws_password)
            logger.info("Email Send To: " + email[1])
            logger.info("Test Point: send_emails: A")
            #server.sendmail(sent_from, email[1], email_body.as_string())
            #REPLACE THIS LINE.  THIS IS JUST FOR TESTING.
            server.sendmail(sent_from, send_to, email_body.as_string())
            server.close()
            insert_into_email_sent_tbl(email[0], "Success")
            logger.info('Email sent!')
            return True

        except Exception as e: 
            logger.info(e)  
            logger.info('Something went wrong...')
            insert_into_email_sent_tbl(email[0], "Fail")
            return False
```

It times out right here with a 10 second time out.  It always stops at this line of code:  `logger.info("send_emails: step 3: smtp")` which means it stops here `server.connect('email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 587)`.

I've given access to both of these email addresses in the SES AWS Console.

Do I have to move the function to `us-east-1`. Please keep in mind that my RDS instance is in `us-east-2`.

**EDIT**

These are my security group rules for outbound:

[image: Outbound Port Rules]

My Inbound rules are as follows:

[image: Inbound Port Rules]

The sources are my work and home machines.

Comment: from a quick read, are you sure you want to have this commented out?  
 `#server.ehlo()`

Comment: Changing it and re-uploading the file now

Comment: No.  It's still timing out.

Comment: how did you go , did you find the issue

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add the host name to the `smtplib.SMTP()` as well

```
print("send_emails: step 1: smtp")
print("send_emails: step 1: smtp")
server = smtplib.SMTP('email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com')
print("send_emails: step 2: smtp")
server.connect('email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 587)
#server.ehlo()
print("send_emails: step 3: smtp")            
server.starttls()
```

looks like its a python [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/44552)

Comment: See above for my inbound and outbound rules.  But I think my outbound rule is compliant with what you said.  My RDS and lambda are in the same region `us-east-2` but SES is only available in `us-east-1`.  Will I have to set up peering between VPCs on each region for this Lambda?  Will this be a problem?

Comment: No you don't need peering just to use ses, we have the same setup at my work.

Comment: updated the answer, this is working for me perfectly.

Comment: logger.info("send_emails: step 1: smtp")
   server = smtplib.SMTP('email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com')
   logger.info("send_emails: step 2: smtp")
   server.connect('email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 587)
   #server.ehlo()
   logger.info("send_emails: step 3: smtp")   
   server.starttls()

Comment: Still not working. Still timing out at the second line.

Comment: I’m using Python 3.6

Comment: i tried in python `3.7.2`, are you limited to using 3.6 only?

Comment: No.  I’ll change it and see.

Comment: Ya try that. I'll run the code in Python 3.6 when I get back

Comment: the suggested change is working for me in python 3.6.5 as well

Comment: I tried it in Python 3.6 and 3.7 in Lambda and it's not working in either.  3.7 because of import issues so I stopped using it that have nothing to do with SMTP (DB stuff) and 3.6 it's not working.  Still timing out.

Comment: what do your security groups look like?  Can you post them because I feel like that's where the issue probably is.

Comment: My outbound rules are fully open

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't try in ec2. I tried this on my Mac. Which Ami are you using

Comment: I'm actually doing this all on Lambda.  My AMI is the Basic Amazon Linux distro.  Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.1.20170812 x86_64 HVM GP2.  However this is all on Lambda which I think is the issue.  I need it to be triggered from an API call.  I'm using Lambda Python 3.6 all else being equal.

Comment: Please note, my EC2 instance operates off the same security groups and I just tried this command ` nc -vz email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 587
Connection to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 587 port [tcp/submission] succeeded!` so it should be able to connect as my outbound rules are fully open as well.

Comment: can you check the subnets of your lambda has routes to internet ? meaning the subnet should have a routing table that should have a route to intetnet gateway for `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205102/discussion-between-arun-k-and-sonofseuss).